# Techniques for keeping your projects on the latest version

Tags: project-management

I'm working on a new project and we're using a pretty nice stack. NHibernate, Spring, MVC... the list goes on.

One thing I've noticed tho is that in the 6 months since we've started we've had a new release of NHibernate, a new release of a third party control toolkit and Windows 7 is on the horizon.

We've had problems before where being stuck on an old version of a technology has cost us dearly, so I'm wondering what are some techniques we could use to help ensure that our transitions to the latest versions of things are as painless as possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the other comments here about updating often. If you wait too long it will be enough work that you will notice it in the project productivity.

The way we do it is the following.

- **One** person on the team, gets the latest version, and makes sure that all tests run.
- That person the upgrades whatever dll's / tools are to be upgraded
- He also documents the upgrade.
- Build all code make necessary changes for it to build
- Run all tests, make sure they run.
- Manual smoke test of UI
- Send info to rest of team with doc of upgrade
- Checkin / make sure it builds on build server

This way we do not loose productivity of the team during the upgrade. Note this would be much more difficult without unit tests.

Answer (score 10):

Quite simply make it a priority and upgrade as you go along. If you keep up-to-date with the latest version, there will be less breaking changes than if you have to update 5 versions at a time.

Perhaps create a branch and do a test update to betas so that you are aware of forthcoming problems when that version RTMs (if using betas is a concern to you).

Comment: Managing changes through branches are definitely an option.

Answer (score 4):

"update early, update often"

if you wait it will be more and more difficult so put high priority on updating the system. Developers mostly like to be on the bleeding edge so they will not mind too much, key challenge is to sell this idea to management.

It is always good to do step by step approach where you upgrade one by one tool. Then it is also easier if you need to roll back to older version. Big bang approach is more difficult and lots of things can go wrong.

Lets be realistic, every update will cost you time and also your team to do the switch to the new tooling version but after some time team learns to deal with it and level of stress when switching the versions is much less.

Comment: This is good in theory, but how do you make sure that you're not introducing problems early and often?

Comment: @lomaxx: if you don't test the upgrade, you're guaranteed to introduce problems later.  Introducing changes is simply part of testing and QA.  It's easy and it should be part of your process.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a management point of view, don't upgrade unless there is a compelling reason. You have to look at what the upgrade brings to your project. If there are no benefits to the upgrade, don't do it. Obviously this isn't a hard and fast rule, but most teams I know don't have time to spend upgrading systems for no reason, they are too busy with feature requests and bug fixes. I recommend working in upgrades on the following basis:

1. The new version runs
   [significantly] faster or more
   efficiently and your
   customers/clients will see this
   improvement or it will reduce your
   immanent hardware needs.
2. Features
   have been added that you or your
   customers/clients want and can take
   [immediate] advantage of.
3. Security enhancement for a security
   flaw that affects your current or
   immediate future architecture.
4. License/support reasons. If you are
   at the end of your contract then you
   will probably want to make the final
   jump to the last version of the
   software that you are entitled to
   while you still have support for the
   upgrade. Alternately if you are on
   such an old version of the software
   that finding support documentation
   for it is difficult then upgrading
   is certainly called for.
5. Some aspect of the project that you are
   working on is directly impacted by
   the software that could be
   upgraded. If you are already going
   to be working with it and testing
   the functionality, it is probably a
   good time to upgrade and [probably]
   won't add significant load to the
   project.
6. Major changes. If your
   project or the software it relies on
   have undergone major changes then it
   is probably a good time to add the
   update(s) into your project plan.
   Major changes implies a more
   difficult upgrade path and should be
   persude on a scheduled basis rather
   than having to be shoe horned in at the last minute due to a needed fix or enhancement.

Specific reasons not to upgrade:

1. Software, installation, and regression testing costs money. Hence the need for a compelling reason to upgrade.
2. New software is often buggy or has unknown "features." For this reason many choose to stay one version behind the latest release.
3. Newer versions can often be slower than previous versions, this is especially true for small updates and patches.
4. Compatibility issues. Upgrades break things, it is better to skip as many incremental upgrades as possible in order to avoid updates that break compatibility, compatibility that may be fixed in the next update.

I recommend keeping a list of all software that your project utilizes along with their version and last upgrade date (along with other important information such as licensing info, support info, etc.). Evaluate every item on this list once a year in order to insure that you don't miss any updates that match a reason to upgrade that you may have missed. Software on this list with an old version/date and a newer version available may be incentive enough to convince management that an upgrade should be done.